# Remove duplicates from django list_filter

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using a list filter in django admin on a field in a related object.

```
class A(models.Model):
   #..
   pass
class B(models.Model):
   fk = models.ForeignKey(A)
   val models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

In the admin for `A`, I'm trying to `list_filter` on `B__val`, but the result is duplicate `A`'s listed for each `B` satisfying the filter value.

Is there an easy way to intercept the query result to remove the duplicates?

Comment: `list_filter = [ B__val ]` in the ModelAdmin registered to `A`

Comment: You could check generated SQL by using django-debug-toolbar, normally Django Admin appends `.distinct()` for spanned lookup like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The admin source indeed tries to add `.distinct()`, but misses it on this for some reason (must be a bug?).

I get the behaviour I'm looking for with the following:

```
class NoDuplicates(ChangeList):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(NoDuplicates,self).__init__(*args)

    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(NoDuplicates,self).get_query_set().distinct()

class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return NoDuplicates

    list_filter = [ B__val ]
```