# ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause ... this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am using MYSQL 5.7. I want to get the recent rows with distinct `device_id`. I tried these queries:

**Query 1**

```
SELECT `table`.`id`, `table`.`device_id` FROM `table` WHERE (id IN (SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date_modified DESC) AS last_modified GROUP BY device_id) and device_id <> '');

+----+------------------+
| id | device_id        |
+----+------------------+
|  5 | ffcecafe5eed4fba |
|  6 | ffcecafe5eed4fba |
|  8 | 71085f00e527bae0 |
+----+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But it's not removing the duplicates.

**SubQuery 1**

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date_modified DESC) AS last_modified GROUP BY device_id;
ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'last_modified.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

This gave error. Then I found on MySQL website to use ANY_VALUE() to remove this error.

**SubQuery 2**

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(id) FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date_modified DESC) AS last_modified GROUP BY device_id;
+---------------+------------------+
| ANY_VALUE(id) | device_id        |
+---------------+------------------+
|             7 |                  |
|             8 | 71085f00e527bae0 |
|             5 | ffcecafe5eed4fba |
+---------------+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is giving distinct ids. But when I am using ANY_VALUE in query 1 above, its giving the same result.

How to query distinct recent rows in MySQL 5.7 ?

---

**Possible Duplicate**

[MySQL 5.7 return all columns of table based on distinct column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293075/mysql-5-7-return-all-columns-of-table-based-on-distinct-column)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: id is neccessory for you?

Comment: @Strawberry I am not asking for making a query for me, I am getting this error ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'last_modified.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @chiragpatel Yes.

Comment: with mysql 5.7 is not more allowed  the use of group by whitout aggregation function  ..  .. if you need  distinct use a proper way  .. a correct related  column set

Comment: @scaisEdge this is incorrect, only MySQL's **default** behaviour has been changed in this regard, but the behaviour is still configurable.

Comment: @shadow  correct  .. is changed  the defaul behaviour and is configurable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query that worked for me-

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM messages m1 LEFT JOIN messages m2
 ON (m1.name = m2.name AND m1.id < m2.id)
WHERE m2.id IS NULL;
```

Thanks @Shadow for the link to the [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group).